# Split a string into an array of strings using substring (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm creating some code that prints a message to console with a border around it to reinforce my programming knowledge. I'm having issues with this specific snippet of code that should be splitting a large string into an array of strings which can then be printed

```
//splits message into multiple parts
//lines is an integer representing how many lines the text would take up within the provided border
//panewidth is an integer representing the desired size of the window created by the borders
    String[] MessageParts = new String[lines];
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
        MessageParts[i] = (message.substring(i*(panewidth-2), (i+1)*(panewidth - 2)));

        //
        //HACK
        System.out.println(MessageParts[i]);
        //

    }
```

Full code:
ChrisMadeaGame Class:

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

package chrismadeagame;

/**
*
* @author 570694
*/
public class ChrisMadeaGame {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

//Generates a statholder object for score
    StatHolder Score = new StatHolder();
    StatHolder Turns = new StatHolder();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    ChrisMadeaGame ChrisMadeaGame = new ChrisMadeaGame();
    ChrisMadeaGame.display("Test");
}

public void display(String message) {
    //Width of pane goes here
    final int panewidth = 80;
    //The character used for the border
    final String BorderChar = "*";
    //The character used for whitespace
    final String WhitespaceChar = " ";

    //Calculates how many lines will be necessary to print the message. Always rounds up to an integer
    final int lines = (int) Math.ceil((panewidth - 2)/message.length());

    //
    //HACK
    System.out.println(lines);
    System.out.println(message.length());
    System.out.println(panewidth);
    System.out.println((panewidth - 2)/message.length());
    //

    //splits message into multiple parts
    String[] MessageParts = new String[lines];
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
        MessageParts[i] = (message.substring(i*(panewidth-2), (i+1)*(panewidth - 2)));

        //
        //HACK
        System.out.println(MessageParts[i]);
        //

    }
    //Prints out the top border
    for (int i = 0; i < panewidth; i++){
        System.out.print(BorderChar);
    }
    System.out.println("");
    //Prints the score line
    System.out.print(BorderChar);
    System.out.print("");
    //Figures out how much whitespace there needs to be after printing the score info
    System.out.print("Score: " + Score.get() + " Turns: " + Turns.get());
    for (int i = 0; i < panewidth -17 - Score.length() - Turns.length(); i++){
        System.out.print(WhitespaceChar);
    }
    System.out.print(BorderChar);
    System.out.println("");
    //prints the message
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
        System.out.print(BorderChar);
        System.out.print(MessageParts[i]);
        System.out.print(BorderChar);
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
}
```

StatHolder Class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package chrismadeagame;

 /**
  *
  * @author 570694
  */
public class StatHolder{
    //Generic object for holding a single integer
    private int stat;
    //Constructor
    public StatHolder(int newStat){
        stat = newStat;
    }   
    public StatHolder(){
        stat = 0;
    }

    //Methods
    public void set(int stat){};
    public int get(){return stat;};
    public int length(){
        return String.valueOf(stat).length();
    }
    };
```

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 78
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
at chrismadeagame.ChrisMadeaGame.display(ChrisMadeaGame.java:50)
at chrismadeagame.ChrisMadeaGame.main(ChrisMadeaGame.java:25)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Please post your full code.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: If you make your question clear, we will be able to help you. On what criteria do you want to split the Strings? Make sure `(panewidth-2)` is not negative.

Comment: The application crashes and the stack trace leads to this for loop. I assumed I did it incorrectly

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Added full code, getting stack trace EDIT: Added stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see there is `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 78` There is no 78th position in your array.

Please check the value for the number of lines because that's what is the size of the array you are defining:
`String[] MessageParts = new String[lines];`

It actually depends on the length of your message:

`final int lines = (int) Math.ceil((panewidth - 2)/message.length());`

Comment: That would make sense, thanks for helping me interpret the stack trace, I really appreciate the help! If I'm interpreting this correctly, I should not exceed the actual length of the string when describing to substring how to break up the string, correct?

Comment: @chaorace: Stacktrace's can be understood by looking at them bottom up. Here the bottom-most line says that cause of exception was at line 25, from where your display method was called inside main, then the exception occurred at line 50 inside display method.. Stacktrace tells you the path which exception followed till it was handled or was submitted to JVM to handle (if not appropriately handled).

Comment: @chaorace or if you prefer you can look at them top-down to see how it propagated through your code till it was handled by JVM. The cause of exception was line 50 and the exception was `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: You should make sure that your array has sufficient space to hold the number of values you want to assign. Your `panewidth`=80. inside the substring() you are getting 80-2=78. And the call made is message.substring(0,78) for i=0. Bam!

Answer (score 0):

what kind of exception do you get? IndexOutOfBOunds?

If that is the case then the string that you pass as parameter can not be sliced in so many parts as the number "lines"

Comment: Stack Trace:

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 78
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
 at chrismadeagame.ChrisMadeaGame.display(ChrisMadeaGame.java:50)
 at chrismadeagame.ChrisMadeaGame.main(ChrisMadeaGame.java:25)
    Java Result: 1

Comment: So yes, this is the problem, you go out of the String length and you get this error. You must be sure that (i+1)*(panewidth - 2) is inside the length of your string